# CSS- How to override properties for div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag inside HTML form.

```
<div class="heading"> </div>
```

For this, I have CSS:

```
.myDiv .heading { 
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ff5450;
}
```

However, I want to override this CSS based on some conditions, i.e. something like:

```
 if(condition === true){
    .myDiv .heading { 
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000000;
    } }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use SASS but it's not that dynamic, if you want to tweak it, then you need to tweak it with JavaScript/

Comment: you can not apply condition in css you can do with php in tag

Comment: What sort of conditions are you looking for? Where are they stored? etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can change the css proerties by using jquery like this
if the condition is true

```
if(condition)
{
  document.getElementByClass("heading").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using JavaScript's ability to change the style of an item? You'd create a JS-file and include it in the `head` section of your HTML page.

Then in your JS file do something like this:

```
if (true) {
    document.getElementById("heading2").style.color= "#000000";
    document.getElementById("heading2").style.fontSize = "14px";
}
```

see: [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: I wouldn't change styles, might be beter to change the class. This way you will keep all the styling in your css files.

Comment: That's even better; didn't think of that immediately but it would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

See :

```js
$('.normal').on('click',function(){
  if($('.normal').hasClass('newClass'))
    $('.normal').removeClass('newClass')
  else
    $('.normal').addClass('newClass');
})
```

```css
.normal{
background-color:red;
font-size:40px;
color:white;
padding:10px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.newClass{
color:red;
background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='normal'>Hello , Click me !</div>
```